# How to force-own Minecraft cats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been having a little bit of a problem with my Minecraft cats.
I've tamed them for a long long time and now I used another launcher, because the one I was using was glitching, and I tamed another cat, after using that new launcher.
Now I can only command my new cat to stand or sit, but the other ones don't seem to recognize me.

**Is there anyway to make my cats be owned by me through the new launcher, like "force own" them?**
I assume I have to use commands, but since it won't give me any game advantage, I don't consider it cheating.

Comment: Launchers shouldn't influence stuff like that. It's either the mod (then list which ones you use) or something in your world got messed up (like adding and later removing a mod or downgrading) or you changed something else.

Comment: sorry messed up thought i was using mods im using optifine. the only thing i did was switch launchers..

Comment: What launchers are you talking about, by the way? Do they have version numbers, or are they modded launchers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done my merging your UUID into the cat's OwnerUUID NBT tag. This command should allow you to do that.

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:cat,distance=..10] run data merge entity @s {OwnerUUID:"yourUUID"}
```

You can check your UUID on https://mcuuid.net/.